# Installing custom fonts on Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, 20.04, fonts

I would like to install a custom TTF or OTF font on Ubuntu Server, but I don't want to have to install a GUI or desktop environment. Is there a way to get this custom font (Fira Code Nerd Font) to be used as the terminal font for Ubuntu Server?

Comment: Is your server going to be headless and only access via SSH?  If so, there is no need for the font on the server level since it is controlled by the terminal application that is running.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49779/can-i-change-the-font-of-the-text-mode-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things you will need to do to make this work. So long as you don't mind fiddling around with fonts, follow these steps:

**I – Convert the `.ttf` font to a `.psf`**

1. Install the `bdf2psf` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install bdf2psf
   ```
2. Convert the font to an intermediary `.bdf`:

   ```
   otf2bdf -p 18 -r 96 -o fc-nerd.bdf fc-nerd.ttf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `fc-nerd` with the actual font name.</sup>

   You may need to modify the `-p` value to match the glyph size, as it's not standard.
3. Convert the `.bdf` to a `.psf`:

   ```
   bdf2psf --fb fc-nerd.bdf /usr/share/bdf2psf/standard.equivalents /usr/share/bdf2psf/fontsets/Uni2.512 512 fc-nerd.psf
   ```
4. Move the file to the appropriate location:

   ```
   mv fc-nerd.psf /usr/share/consolefonts/fc-nerd.psf
   ```

**II – Set the Font**

1. Use `setfont` to configure the console:

   ```
   setfont fc-nerd
   ```

If the font doesn't look right, go back to the first set of steps and modify that `-p` value until it looks better.

If you would like to use the font every time you sign into the console, you can add the `setfont` command to the end of your `~/.bashrc` file.